# Using CUDA in Colab

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

Is it necessary to convert tensors and models to CUDA with `tensor.to` in colab when I've chosen runtime type as GPU?

I want use CUDA for training my model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- tensor.to(device) transfer data to the given device.
- Yes, you need to transfer model, input, labels etc to whatever device you are intending to use

Comment: Do note: `torch.Tensor.to` makes a copy while `torch.nn.Module.to` is an in-place operation.